# The MyBB upgrage 1.6 > 1.8 stucks on Database updating

Tags: php, mysql, upgrade, forum, mybb

I attempted to upgrade my MyBB forum from 1.6.18 version to 1.18.21.
The script stuck at Database updating:

> Updating Database
>   Performing necessary upgrade queries...
>   Click next to continue with the upgrade process.

Then instead there is a button that can't be clicked [Automatically Redirecting...]

My site is hosted on a free hosting, so I thinked it is not much powerful to do an ugpgrade, also if my db is not so big, just 55mb.
Then I setup AAMPS on my pc and tried on that.
I edited mysql config file to increment max_allowed_packet to 1000m
But incredibly............ it stucks EXACTLY at the same point with the same result. I left the page for more than 1 hour and it's still stay on the Updating Database page.

Can someone help me please?
I maybe should edit some php or mysql config?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the current minimum requirements to upgrade to make sure that you have
enough resources like PHP version, Mysql and diskspace, etc...

If you are on Chrome, you can use the Developer tools to inspect the page and look for any console error. Another way to detect the issue is to enable the warnings in php.ini file. This would help us identify the issue and then we can look forward to solutions to resolve the same.

> Reference to enable warning: 
>   [Showing all errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings/5438125)

Give this a try and post back with the errors you have identified and we shall try to resolve it.